# How can I find Thévenin equivalent circuit of the NFB op-amp input?

Tags: operational-amplifier, thevenin, inverting-amplifier, non-inverting, virtual-ground

[image]

I need to find the Thévenin equivalent of the right side of the circuit by looking into node E and F. How can I find it?

Comment: Hint: Redraw the amplifiers as their equivalent circuit models.

Comment: I draw about it, but it has Voc=0 and Isc=0, so I think it is neither open or short(without the value of i2, the current of F=0)

Answer (score 3):

That's a nasty question.

The trick is to realise that node E is a virtual Earth, always 0V, maintained by the right-hand op-amp itself. Assuming that op-amp is ideal, the Thevenin equivalent between E and F is:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdzzwq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Don't be fooled into thinking that \$V_2=0\$, therefore. The op-amp will always produce whatever output \$V_2\$ is necessary to equalise its two inputs (inverting and non-inverting). That means *exactly all of* \$I_2\$ is actually sourced/sunk by that output, *as if* E were directly connected to ground.

---

In response to your question in the comments, the premise is that a Thevenin equivalent must simply represent a resistance in series with a voltage source to anyhting connected between its two terminals.

Any external source of current connected between those terminals need not know anything about the circuit inside the equivalent's "black box", including what that boxes' own idea of ground is. The only requirement is that current leaving the source and entering the box must also leave the box and return to the source:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faEXXi.png)</sup>

Notice that I haven't even labelled ground in that circuit. It's irrelevant. It's just a name saying "Here is what I shall call zero volts".

The current path shown is for \$I_2 > 0\$ (positive), and the op-amp output is sinking that current. If \$I_2 < 0\$ then the op-amp output would source that current instead, which would flow via its positive supply.

---

It's worth noting that this Thevenin equivalence will only be true as long as the op-amp's output is able to sink/source current \$I_2\$. Most op-amps will be limited in this respect, to a couple of tens of milliamps.

For example, if you were to replace the source of \$I_2\$ with a voltage source of low internal resistance, the resulting current would certainly exceed the op-amp's capabilities, and the equivalence will be lost, since the op-amp will not be able to maintain the condition \$V_{INV}=V_{NONINV}\$.

Other non-idealities of the op-amp will also affect equivalency. For instance, if \$I_2\$ changes more quickly than the op-amp can respond, which depends on the op-amp's slew rate and bandwidth, then momentarily \$V_{INV} \ne V_{NONINV}\$. Op-amp input offset voltage and bias currents will also cause \$V_{INV} \ne V_{NONINV}\$, by a difference of several millivolts, potentially.

Comment: Ground in thevenin circuit is necessary? If necessary, would you explain why it is necessary?

Comment: @LSK It's not necessary. It's just a way of saying "here is what I shall called zero volts", and I only included it because F is connected to ground in your schematic. It's good that you pointed that out. Actually, the Thevenin equivalent is really only concerned with a potential difference, not any absolute potential anywhere.

Comment: In the circuit, the current of F is 0 regardless of i2. However, the thevenin circuit seems that current of F = i2. Then, is this a equivalent circuit?

Comment: @LSK see my update

Answer (score 3):

## Beyond formal explanations

The answer is obvious: *Looking at the op-amp input in a circuit with negative feedback you see zero resistance*. It will probably do you a good job. But in addition, we have the unique opportunity to investigate exactly how this happens in this odd circuit with two interacting op-amps.

## Looking for something familiar

Let's first try to recognize some functional circuit building blocks. The first thing we need to do is remove the resistor connected in series with the inverting input of the op-amp on the left because its influence here is negligible (due to the negligible op-amp input current). So it is not essential to understanding the ideas here. Then let's outline the recognized sub-circuits with a dashed line.

## Configurations

### Disturbed follower and inverting amplifier

The first thing we see is that a *voltage follower* is made through OA1. But it is strange why there is a resistor (R1) connected between the output and the inverting input. Is not that redundant too? Obviously not because the significant op-amp output current flows through it. So this resistor disturbs the op-amp and makes it work harder than necessary to overcome it; hence the figurative name "disturbed follower".

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwhS6P.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The next sub-circuit (R2, R3 and OA2) is well known to us - it is the famous *inverting amplifier*.

### Current source and transimpedance amplifier

We can group the elements in another way. For example, in the combination of OA1, R1 and R2 we can recognize a *current source*.  In fact, it consists of two sub-circuits - the *disturbed voltage follower* (OA1 and R1) and a *voltage-to-current converter* (R2).

Then, in the sub-circuit of only two elements (OA2 and R3), we can recognize another famous circuit - the *transimpedance amplifier*.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNU0Tz.png)</sup>

### Virtually grounded non-inverting amplifier

If we go back to the "disturbed follower" (OA1 and R1), we can realize that in its effort to compensate for the disturbance it has become an amplifier. The role of R2 is to draw a current that creates the "disturbing" voltage drop VR1.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5SpnB.png)</sup>

The only difference between this and classic *non-inverting amplifier* is that it is *virtually grounded*.

## Operation

It is interesting that in this configuration, the two op-amp outputs are connected through a 3-resistor network to each other, and their inputs are connected to the two intermediate points between the resistors in such a way that they "fight" each other like in a game of "tag of war". Each of them seeks to establish zero voltage between its two inputs by influencing the other. The interesting thing is that, in the end, both manage to achieve it, and an equilibrium occurs (with this behavior the circuit reminds the famous transistor *cascode configuration*). Of course, all this takes place in a very short time (us or ns) and practically happens simultaneously and instantaneously. But in order to follow it with our slow human thinking, we can slow it down many times and reduce it to a few steps (moments of time).

### Vin = 0 V

For this purpose, we can replace the op-amps (OA1 and OA2) with variable voltage sources (VOA1 and VOA2), and manually control them in this manner (e. g., you control VOA1, and I control VOA2). Also, we can connect two voltmeters (VOA1- and VOA2-) to observe the voltages at the op-amp inverting inputs. Note that VOA1- = Vin and VOA2- = 0 V in a state of equilibrium. In the initial state (when Vin = 0 V), all voltages are zero, and no currents flow.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIERJM.png)</sup>

### Vin = 1 V

**t1: VOA1 = 1.5 V, VOA2 = 0 V.** Imagine that at the moment t1 the input voltage Vin changes from zero to 1 V. You immediately react to this "intervention" and begin increasing VOA1 (to 1.5 V) until VOA1- = 1 V (*virtual short*). I fail to react and my voltage VOA2 = 0. As a result, you have achieved your goal (VOA1- = 1 V) but I have not (VOA2- = 500 mV, not zero).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDiV4d.png)</sup>

As I said above, in practice the two voltages (VOA1 and VOA2) change at the same time, but in order to understand it, it is good to separate them in time.

**t2: VOA1 = 1.5 V, VOA2 = -0.75 V.** So, at next moment, I begin decreasing my voltage VOA2 to -750 mV until VOA2- = 0 V (*virtual ground*). However, this is how I change your voltage VOA1- and it drops to 750 mV.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fax8yV.png)</sup>

**t3: VOA1 = 2 V, VOA2 = -1 V.** You notice this and start increasing VOA1 finally to 2 V until you recover your voltage VOA1- = 1 V (at the same time, I make sure my voltage stays at zero).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fF18gu.png)</sup>

Comment: I was forced to post my answer in a still unfinished form due to the danger of the question being closed. I will add explanations later.

Answer (score 1):

The op-amp circuit connected to (E,F) is incomplete although the rest of the circuit is implied as is usually the case for op-amps. Here though what is implicit must be made clear.

For the Thevenin circuit to be complete, the current entering E must leave F. Since the op-amp input cannot supply that current, there is a missing ground to the right of the dashed line.

The power distribution network connections and current paths must be clarified. (Simon's answer does this).

At the very least, a right side ground connection must be included as shown in Figure 1, since that is where the current leaving F is sourced from.

Since \$v_{\text{oc}}=0\$ by op=amp action, \$i_{\text{sc}}=0\$ must also be true. So these two measurements are insufficient to determine \$R_{Th}\$. This is true any time there is no voltage source to work with.

So a various currents must be applied (theoretically), then by op-amp action, the voltage open circuit voltage does not change, so \$R_{Th}=0\$.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiuDvX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Thévenin equivalent for this is wanted. Here's some help. Start by noticing that F is op-amp input, it's NOT the ground.

[image]

To make the Thévenin equivalent concept meaningful the circuit should be linear. It's possible to use a linearized model for the op-amp, but that model should be known to find the Thévenin equivalent.

The next linearized model assumes there's some DC bias and resistive inputs. The output is generated by a controlled voltage source with limited gain G.

[image]

Insert an input voltage Uin between E and F. Calculate the input current Iin. The result is a formula. To see the Thévenin equivalent reshape that formula into the format

Uin = Et + Rt * Iin

The result changes radically if you insert some external connections between the op-amp's ground and the inputs E and F. I assumed there are none. I'm afraid all applications have such connections. To get anything useful they should be inserted to the model . Your original application connects F directly to the ground which very likely is the same as the ground of the op-amp.

You may say *What the f...! Why the external connection, for example connecting F to the ground should be taken into the account when  calculating the Thevenin equivqlent? Shouldn't Thevenin equivalent be universally valid for all possible external world circuits connected to E and F?*

My answer: Thevenin equivqlent is valid only if you connect from external world something(=anything) only to E and F. If you make a third connection between the modeled circuit and the external world, the Thevenin equivalent is no more valid.